# Using the "true" sample rather than sampling from a distribution - is there a name for this?

Tags: terminology, simulation

I have drawn X-many samples from a population. I want to use this data to drive inputs for a Monte Carlo simulation (or similar). The population may be a real world measurement, or it could be the output of another computer model.

There are two ways I could go about this:

- I could use the samples to estimate a population distribution and sample from the estimated distribution within the Monte Carlo simulation.
- I could randomly draw from the samples that I have already collected from the population.

Both of these approaches have strengths and weaknesses and are appropriate in some situations and less useful in others.

Is there better terminology that I can use if/when I want to discuss the distinction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both these approaches are considered two different versions of the [bootstrap](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat555/node/119/#:%7E:text=Parametric%20bootstrap,or%20normal%20for%20continuous%20distribution.)

In the case that we are fitting the distribution to a parametric model and then sampling from the model, this is called the parametric bootstrap. If we simply resample the raw data directly, this is referred to the non-parametric bootstrap.

In practice, the non-parametric bootstrap is used much more often, due to being simpler and having less assumptions attached. As such, when people refer to simply "bootstrap", they usually mean the non-parametric approach.

Answer (score 6):

This is called an *Empirical distribution function*. You can check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function).

Comment: Super, thanks! That gives me two straightforward ways to describe the difference: "Empirical distribution vs Estimated distribution" and "parametric vs non-parametric bootstrap".

Comment: I marked the other answer as correct but if I could then I'd have ticked both.